# Material UI TextField with specific date format

Tags: material-ui

I am new to Material UI and I am currently working on TextField display with datetime. I tested the code in https://material-ui.com/demos/pickers/. That fits our needs.

However, I would like to change the date format and I found that it is implemented by `<input>` element.
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/10251

May I have some sample code to achieve this requirement?
The TextField display on my screen was in Chinese (as my regional setting is Hong Kong?), I would like to change it to display it in English. Besides, the date format is DD/MM/YYYY HH:SS. I want to change it to "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:SS"

[TextField with datetime-local on my PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLeKD.png)

Here below is the code:

```
    <TextField
      id="datetime-local"
      label="From"
      type="datetime-local"
      defaultValue="2017-05-24T10:30"
      className={classes.textField}
      variant="outlined"
      InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: true,
      }}
    />

    <TextField
      id="datetime-local"
      label="To"
      type="datetime-local"
      defaultValue="2017-05-24T10:30"
      className={classes.textField}
      variant="outlined"
      InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: true,
      }}
    />
```

BTW, I have also tested material-ui-picker which does not fulfill the requirement from our BI.
Any advice on changing TextField datetime format is appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `type="datetime-local"` prop is a native `<input>` element attribute. You are limited by the formatting your browser is supporting. You have two options.

1. If you want to stay with a native implementation, you can provide a custom `inputComponent` prop that handles the formatting with a library like date-fns or moment.
2. You can use https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/ that handles the formatting outside of the box.