# Unable to format the date using material-ui Date & Time pickers

Tags: material-ui

Hi My object is to format the date in the form of MM-DD-YYYY but it is showing in the form of dd-mm-yyyy --:--. but couldn't able to do it. i don't know where i'm going wrong. i want in this format MM-DD-YYYY H:M.

Here is the code:

```
    < TextField
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    id="datetime-local"
                                    label="Select Date and Time"
                                    placeholder="Select Date and Time"
                                    type="datetime-local"
                                    value={this.state.DateTime}
                                    InputLabelProps={{
                                        shrink: true,
                                    }}
                                    onChange={this.HandleChange}
                                />


HandleChange = (e) => {
this.setState({DateTime: e.target.value})
}
```

Here is the link which i've referred "https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/"

Can anyone please help me in this query? thanks in advance

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55040496/9449426) answer

Comment: @NearHuscarl - I've seen this example but not sure how to implement the first point in my code. Could you help me in this?